# Android databinding deprecated?

Tags: android, android-data-binding

От многих людей слышу, что Google обьявил о том, databinding объявлен deprecated, однако на официальном сайте ничего подобного не нашел. Гугл тоже ничего вразумительного не выдает. Есть ли действительно какая-то официальная информация на этот счет?

Comment: `depricated` — очень меткое английское слово. Но это сообщество на русском языке — так что переведите его ("больше не поддерживается" например).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor категорически не согласен. `deprecated` - это устойчивый термин, по крайней мере в среде Java/Android разработчиков. Все кому надо поняли.

Comment: @Barmaley Конечно поняли. Среди Питон разработчиков тоже. Но если аргумент "все кому надо поняли" — то давайте вообще по-английски писать — всем же все ясно. Мои написания по-английски получали правки и комменты — считаю справедливо. Так что "понятно" — не аргумент.

Comment: Ну давайте тогда переведем и data binding и Activity, да и метки java, android - заодно, чего уж мелочиться то?

Comment: @Barmaley Они так по-русски и называются. В отличии от "deprecated".

Comment: @Barmaley Переводить "java" так же глупо как перевести на русский язык например название государства. Мы же не переводим например слово "Франция". А "deprecated" можно и нужно перевести. Это обычное слово — не название.

Comment: `deprecated` - это стандартная Java аннотация, практически ключевое слово - нет необходимости в переводе. В общем каждый остается на своем, все расходимся :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вряд ли. Скорее всего имеется ввиду, что ранее в gradle надо было прописывать поддержку data binding как:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

В новой версии плагина Android Gradle >= 4.0 это действительно объявлено `deprecated`, теперь православным признается способ:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```